# How multiply two lists with each other?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Help solve the problem. There is a database that contains two tables, for example:

**Table 1 - prices**

```
Base Metals 165.0
Condensates 130.0
Condensed Alloy 200.0
```

**Table 2 - resource**

```
Base Metals 8.04
Condensates 19.83
Condensed Alloy 30.21
```

I want to multiply all the values from the second column and get a list that will need to be added to the base (SQLite) like this:

```
Base Metals 1326.6
Condensates 2577.9
Condensed Alloy 6042.0
```

The maximum that I got was to select values from the list, add them to the array, in this way:

```
prices_arr = []
planetary_arr = []

for row in cursor.execute("SELECT name, highest_buy FROM prices ORDER BY name"):
    prices_arr.append(row)

for row in cursor.execute("SELECT resource, mining_hour FROM planetary ORDER BY resource"):
    planetary_arr.append(row)
```

But how to multiply the values and leave the names in the list, I don't understand. Tried doing through NumPy, removing "names" from arrays, and leaving only values, but I don't understand how I can combine them with names.

```
for row in cursor.execute("SELECT highest_buy FROM prices ORDER BY name"):
    prices_arr.append(row)

for row in cursor.execute("SELECT mining_hour FROM planetary ORDER BY resource"):
    planetary_arr.append(row)

result = np.multiply(prices_arr,planetary_arr)
```

**Output**

```
[[1326.6 ]
[2577.9 ]
[6042.  ]...
```

Comment: It would be useful to see prices_arr and planetary_arr since your question is multiplying lists not database-specific.

Comment: `prices_arr = [('Base Metals', 165.0), ('Condensates', 130.0), ('Condensed Alloy', 200.0)] planetary_arr = [('Base Metals', 8.04), ('Condensates', 19.83), ('Condensed Alloy', 30.21)]`

Comment: does this have anything to do with numpy?

Comment: I wrote that I tried to do it through numpy, which in my understanding means that I am ready to use this tool, if it has such functionality.

Comment: it is almost trivial with pandas. Are you ok using it?

Comment: Yes thank you. It would be very interesting to see an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = [(entry1[0], entry1[1] * entry2[1]) for entry1, entry2 in zip(prices_arr, planetary_arr)]
```

This is what you asked for, but I think using a dictionary similar to @8hubham sugested may be a better approach.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But why do some values take the form: [('Base Metals', 1326.6), ('Condensates', 2577.8999999999996), ('Condensed Alloy', 6042.0)], How can this be fixed, and what could be the problem? Sorry for the silly questions, I have been trying to program not so long ago.

Comment: That's just the nature of floating point numbers. You have two options. Ignore that until you print or store as a string and set the precision then. That's the recommended approach. The alternative is to used round() to round the value to a set number of decimal places.